# Solve the equation $\;x'=\frac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the equation $\;x'=\dfrac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}$

I solved this problem, but I'm not sure if it's correct:
$$x' =\frac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}$$
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}$$
$$(2x+t)dx = (x+2t-6)dt$$
$$\int (2x+t)dx = \int (x+2t-6)dt$$
$$x^2+xt=tx+t^2-6t+C$$
$$x^2=t^2-6t+C$$
$$x(t)=\pm \sqrt{t^2-6t+C}$$

Comment: For differential equations like this it is often possible to just plug and chug to check your answer: you have an expression that you can replace x with, what happens when you plug it back in to the original equation?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use the method of separation of variables, and as the name says, you should separate the variables first, so all $x$'s in one side and all $t$'s on the other. One of the mistakes that should give it away to you that something went wrong, is that $x$ is a function of $t$, so $x(t)$, yet going from the 4th to the 5th line you treated it as a constant when integrating with respect to $t$. And a similar, problem arises on the left side of the equation, so your solution is not correct

Comment: The integral of $tdx$ is not $tx,$ because $x$ is a function of $t.$ And similarly for the integral of $xdt.$ It might help if you write $x$ as a function of $t,$ $x(t).$ Then you'll see why you don't get simple integrals for $\int t\,dx(t)$ and $\int x(t)\,dt.$

Answer (score 1):

> Solve the differential equation $\;x'=\dfrac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}\quad\color{blue}{(*)}$

We can obtain the general solution through the following change of variable:$$u=\dfrac{x+2}{t-4}\,.$$

It results that $\;x=ut-4u-2\;,\;$ so the differential equation $\,(*)\,$ turns into :

$u’t+u-4u’=\dfrac{ut-4u-8+2t}{2ut-8u-4+t}\;\;,$

$u’t+u-4u’=\dfrac{(u+2)(t-4)}{(2u+1)(t-4)}\;\;,$

$u’(t-4)=\dfrac{u+2}{2u+1}-u\;\;,$

$u’(t-4)=\dfrac{2(1-u^2)}{2u+1}\;.\quad\color{blue}{(**)}$

$u_1(t)=-1\;$ and $\;u_2(t)=1\;$ are two particular solutions of the differential equation $\,(**)\,.$

Consequently ,

$x_1(t)=2-t\;$ and $\;x_2(t)=t-6\;$ are two particular solutions of the differential equation $\,(*)\,.$

From $\,(**)\,,\,$ for any function $\;u\neq u_1\;\land\;u\neq u_2\,,\;$ we get that

$\displaystyle\int\dfrac{2u+1}{2(1-u^2)}\,\mathrm du=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{t-4}\;\;,$

$\displaystyle\int\left[-\dfrac1{4(u+1)}-\dfrac3{4(u-1)}\right]\!\mathrm du=\int\dfrac{\mathrm dt}{t-4}\;\;,$

$-\dfrac14\ln|u+1|-\dfrac34\ln|u-1|=\ln|t-4|+C\;\;,$

$\ln|u+1|+3\ln|u-1|+4\ln|t-4|=-4C\;\;,$

$|u+1||u-1|^3|t-4|^4=k\;\;,\;\;$ where $\;k=e^{-4C}>0\,.$

Since $\;u=\dfrac{x+2}{t-4}\;,\;$ we get that

$\left|\dfrac{x+2}{t-4}+1\right|\left|\dfrac{x+2}{t-4}-1\right|^3|t-4|^4=k\;\;,$

$\left|\dfrac{x+t-2}{t-4}\right|\left|\dfrac{x-t+6}{t-4}\right|^3|t-4|^4=k\;\;,$

$|x+t-2||x-t+6|^3=k\;\;,\;\;$ where $\;k>0\,.$

But, for $\,k=0\,,\,$ we get the particular solutions :

$x_1(t)=2-t\;$ and $\;x_2(t)=t-6\;\;$

hence, the general solution of the differential equation $\,(*)\,$ is

$|x+t-2||x-t+6|^3=k\;\;,\;\;$ where $\;k\geqslant0\,.$

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide another approach:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'(\tau) \\ t'(\tau)
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}
x(\tau) \\ t(\tau)
\end{bmatrix}
+
\begin{bmatrix}
-6 \\ 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Based on $x'(t)=\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{\frac{dx}{d\tau}}{\frac{dt}{d\tau}}=\frac{x(\tau)+2t(\tau)-6}{2x(\tau)+t(\tau)}$

The aequilibrium of the system $x'(\tau)=0, t'(\tau)=0$ is at $x=-2$, $t=4$.

The system has 2 real-valued eigenvalues $[-1,3]$.
Unfortunately eigenvalue $3$ is not stable.

We are able to derive an explicit general solution:

$x(\tau)=e^{3 \tau } \left(\frac{t_0}{2}+\frac{x_0}{2}-1\right)+e^{-\tau } \left(-\frac{t_0}{2}+\frac{x_0}{2}+3\right)-2$

$t(\tau)=e^{3 \tau } \left(\frac{t_0}{2}+\frac{x_0}{2}-1\right)+e^{-\tau } \left(\frac{t_0}{2}-\frac{x_0}{2}-3\right)+4$

with $x_0=x(0)$, $t_0=t(0)$.

The instable term $e^{3 \tau}$ can be disabled if the initial conditions $t_0+x_0=2$.
In this case the system will tend to its aequilibrium point.

See also a phase portrait of the linear ODE system with $x_0=3, t_0=0, 0\le \tau \le 0.8$:

[image]

and verify it with @Angelo's implicit formula ($k=|-t_0+x_0+6|^3|t_0+x_0-2|=729$):

[image]

In fact, it fits perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}$$
HINT :
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{ (x+2)+2(t-4)}{2(x+2)+(t-4)}$$
Change of variables : $\quad\begin{cases}
\xi=x+2\\
\tau=t-4
\end{cases}$
$$\frac{d\xi}{d\tau}=\frac{\xi+2\tau}{2\xi+\tau}$$
Now this is an homogeneos ODE. The usual change of function is :
$$\xi(\tau)=\tau\: y(\tau)\quad\implies\quad \frac{d\xi}{d\tau}=y+\tau\frac{dy}{d\tau}$$
$$\frac{d\xi}{d\tau}=\frac{\xi+2\tau}{2\xi+\tau}=y+\tau\frac{dy}{d\tau}=\frac{\tau \: y+2\tau}{2\tau \:y+\tau}=\frac{y+2}{2y+1}$$
$$\tau\frac{dy}{d\tau}=\frac{y+2}{2y+1}-y$$
Now the OE is separable :
$$\frac{1}{\tau}d\tau=\frac{1}{\frac{y+2}{2y+1}-y}dy$$
$$\ln|\tau|=\frac12 \int \frac{2y+1}{-y^2+1}dy+C$$
I suppose that you can continue.

Comment: There is a mistake in the last equality.

Comment: @Angelo : OK. Thank you. Typo corrected.

Comment: @JJacquelin I get $\tau_1=-\exp(\frac 14 (\ln (y+1) + 3\ln(y-1))+C_1)$ and $\tau_2=\exp(\frac 14 (\ln (y+1) + 3\ln(y-1))+C_1)$. Is this the final answer or can we discard one of the solutions?

Comment: $\tau=c\:(1-y)^{3/4}(1+y)^{1/4}$ .

Comment: @JJacquelin This is the only solution? Why do we reject $\tau=-c\:(1-y)^{3/4}(1+y)^{1/4}$?

Comment: $\pm c$ both are the same since $c$ can be positive or negative.

Comment: @JJacquelin How to give the final answer? Do we have to go back to $x(t)$?

Answer (score -1):

We can get 2 solutions using the ansatz $x=mt+b$ (method of undetermined coefficients)

$$x' =\frac{ x+2t-6}{2x+t}\implies m[2(mt+b)+t]=mt+b+2t-6$$

Equating coefficients of $t$...
$$2m^2+m= m+2  $$
and $$ 2mb=b-6$$

the first equation has solutions $m=\pm1$ and the second gives $b=-\frac 6{2m-1}$

So two solutions are...
$$x_1(t) = t-6 \text{ and } x_2(t)= -t+2$$

Comment: Please, write in English not in German, write “approach”, not “ansatz”.

Comment: @Angelo   "Ansatz" is a standard term in physics/mathematics across languages, even if it is borrowed from German (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ansatz).

Comment: $x_1(t) = t-6$  and  $ x_2(t)= -t+2$ are two particular solutions. But they are not the complete solution of the ODE.